# forEach keeps adding 1 value to the next result

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service that returns this data as a response,

```
{"id":157336,"results":[
    {"id":"53db3c790e0a26189a000d09","iso_639_1":"en","key":"ePbKGoIGAXY","name":"Trailer 3","site":"YouTube","size":1080,"type":"Trailer"},
    {"id":"550df44b9251413554004d43","iso_639_1":"en","key":"KlyknsTJk0w","name":"Own it today","site":"YouTube","size":720,"type":"Trailer"},
    {"id":"533ec6fcc3a3685448009ccc","iso_639_1":"en","key":"nyc6RJEEe0U","name":"Teaser","site":"YouTube","size":720,"type":"Trailer"},
    {"id":"5376ab510e0a26141c0005a8","iso_639_1":"en","key":"zSWdZVtXT7E","name":"Trailer","site":"YouTube","size":720,"type":"Trailer"},
    {"id":"545da247c3a3685362005187","iso_639_1":"en","key":"Lm8p5rlrSkY","name":"Trailer 2","site":"YouTube","size":1080,"type":"Trailer"}
]}
```

Then if I do a `forEach` loop it adds adds the next result to the previous results,

```
$scope.youtubeTrailer = [];
angular.forEach(response.results, function(item){
  if (item.hasOwnProperty('key')) {
    $scope.youtubeTrailer.push(item.key);
    console.log ($scope.youtubeTrailer)
  }
})
```

Resulting in this output,

```
["ePbKGoIGAXY"]
["ePbKGoIGAXY", "KlyknsTJk0w"]
["ePbKGoIGAXY", "KlyknsTJk0w", "nyc6RJEEe0U"]
["ePbKGoIGAXY", "KlyknsTJk0w", "nyc6RJEEe0U", "zSWdZVtXT7E"]
["ePbKGoIGAXY", "KlyknsTJk0w", "nyc6RJEEe0U", "zSWdZVtXT7E", "Lm8p5rlrSkY"]
```

Is there a way to loop through each unique item? So the output would be,

```
["ePbKGoIGAXY"]
["KlyknsTJk0w"]
["nyc6RJEEe0U"]
["zSWdZVtXT7E"]
["Lm8p5rlrSkY"]
```

Comment: Just so we're clear:  you *intend* to add those values to the array, right?  You *intend* to have the array fill up with more than one YouTube ID, right?

Comment: @Makoto, I'm thinking either you're right or the code is simplified for SO.

Comment: I want to save every value in a table separately, so I'll put in a create service in the `forEach` as well.

Comment: Also why is this question downvote so much? I presented a question, data, expection etc. Both the answers I got worked great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using youtubeTrailer for something, you could empty it on each iteration, before pushing to it.

```
angular.forEach(response.results, function(item){
  if (item.hasOwnProperty('key')) {
    $scope.youtubeTrailer = [];
    $scope.youtubeTrailer.push(item.key);
    console.log ($scope.youtubeTrailer)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing out the array in each iteration of the loop `console.log ($scope.youtubeTrailer)`.  If you just want to just see the current item printed, just log item.key `console.log(item.key)`